# Error in parsing value for ‘background’. Declaration dropped. , what do this error means?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

```js
let color = [
    "#E27D60",
    "#85DCB",
    "#E8A87C",
    "#C38D9E",
    "#41B3A3",
    "#242582",
    "#553D67",
    "#F64C72",
    "#99738E",
]
let point;
let _cC;
let _cN;

let randCol = (pack) => {

    point = Math.floor(Math.random() * pack.length);

    _cC = document.body.style.background = pack[point];
    switch(_cC){
        case "#E27D60":
        _cN = ' Terracotta';
        break;

        case "#85DCB":
        _cN = " Mintgreen";
        break;

        case "#E8A87C":
        _cN = " Tacao";
        break;

        case "#C38D9E":
        _cN = " Oriental Pink";
        break;

        case "#41B3A3":
        _cN = " Keppel";
        break;

        case "#242582":
        _cN = " Jacksons Purple";
        break;

        case "#553D67":
        _cN = " Mulled Wine";
        break;

        case "#F64C72":
        _cN = " French Rose";
        break;

        case "#99738E":
        _cN = " Mountbatten Pink";
        break;

        default:
            _cN = " black";
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById("cN").innerHTML = _cN;
console.log(_cC);
console.log(_cN)


    document.getElementById('change-me').style.background = pack[point];
}

let r = () => randCol(color);

document.getElementById('change-me').addEventListener("click", r);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Roboto:wght@100;500&display=swap');

@keyframes spin {
    100%{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

$fist-color: #D83F87;
$second-color: #2A1B3D;
$third-color: #44318D;
$fourth-color: #FAED26;
$fifth-color: #F79E02;
$sixth-color: #0074E1;
body{
    background:black;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1{
    font-weight: 500;
}
.animate{
    margin-top: 2rem;
    background-color:black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.animate::before{
    content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 350px;
height: 350px;
border-radius: 10px;
    background: conic-gradient(from 55deg
    ,$fist-color,$fist-color 60deg
    , $second-color 60deg, $second-color 120deg
    , $third-color 120deg, $third-color 180deg
    , $fourth-color 180deg, $fourth-color 240deg
    , $fifth-color 240deg, $fifth-color 300deg
    , $sixth-color 300deg, $sixth-color 360deg
    ); 
  
animation: spin 10s infinite linear ;
}

button{
   position: absolute;
   width: 230px;
   height: 230px;
   background:black;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 10px;
   color: white;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
   font-size: 22px;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="scss/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ranodom Color | color changer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Background-color:<span id="cN"> Black</span></h1>
    <div class="animate">
        <button id="change-me">Change Color</button>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Been trying to make this beginners project, and stumbled across this error in the console, it's delaying my color names when i click, I looked up online but didn't find a way to get past it.
The code works fine but randomly this errors pops up and after that the next click does nothing.
I tried re-structuring my CSS but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What browsers/versions are you coding for?

Comment: I am currently on firefox version: 94.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: It looks as though you are using SCSS not pure CSS and that the error comes from SCSS not understanding your conic-gradient setting. If you are using SCSS could you tag the question as such and also make sure your snippet works with SCSS. At the moment we won't see the problem because SCSS isn't loading.

Comment: yes, i will do that

Comment: https://github.com/Alucard2169/random-changer

Comment: you can check the whole code here https://github.com/Alucard2169/random-changer